# How do I assign variables to function depending on a class or group?

Tags: python

What I am trying to do is something like this:

```
if (color = "red"):
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3
    break

if (color = "blue"):
    a = 5
    b = 6
    c = 7
    break

color = "blue"
z = a + b + c


print("The answer is = " + str(z))
```

I have several classes would like to assign values of variables to and then pull those values depending on which class I define. Is this possible?

Comment: The question seems a bit unclear, but you can define default values for variables in the class constructor like so `def __init__(self, x = "default value")`

Comment: Are you asking how to take those `if` statements and put them in a function that you can call?

Comment: Okay abarnert. I understand what you are saying to do. I am very new to python and am trying to learn as I go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the simple solution is to use a dictionary, grouping the value for each color:

```
classes = {'red':[1,2,3], 'blue':[5,6,7]} #etc...
color='red'
a,b,c = classes[color]
z = a + b + c
print('The answer is', z)
```

if the number of value differs from a color to the next:

```
z=sum(classes[color])
print('The answer is', z)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean *class* as a *group* rather than the programming definition, you can use a dictionary for a variable number of variables.

In this case, you can use a nested dictionary and access values with O(1) complexity.

```
d = {'red': {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3},
     'blue': {'a': 5, 'b': 6, 'c': 7}}

color = 'blue'
d_color = d[color]
z = d_color['a'] + d_color['b'] + d_color['c']

print("The answer is = " + str(z))
# The answer is = 18
```

Or, more simply, you can sum all values in a dictionary via `sum` and `dict.values`:

```
z = sum(d['blue'].values())
```

Comment: Thank you very much jpp. That is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: @cheme_wilson, Sure, no problem. Feel free to accept an answer that helped.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that what you're asking how to do is how to put all those `if` statements (presumably your real code has more than two?) into a function, and then call that function? (And that by "class" you don't mean it in Python/OO terms, but rather just… some group of values?)

If so:

```
# Define a function that takes color as a parameter
def colorvals(color):
    # Indent your existing if statements to make them part of the function.
    # You also need to fix the = SyntaxError; use == for comparison
    if (color == "red"):
        a = 1
        b = 2
        c = 3
        break

    if (color == "blue"):
        a = 5
        b = 6
        c = 7
        break

    # At the end, return the values to the caller.
    return a, b, c

color = "blue"
# Now you can call that function and use the results.
a, b, c = colorvals(color)
z = a + b + c
```

---

There are ways you could improve this:

- The parens in each `if` are meaningless.
- The `break`s do nothing.
- It's probably clearer to write `a, b, c = 1, 2, 3`… or just `return 1, 2, 3`.
- You probably want `elif` rather than `if` for each condition after the first.
- You probably want some error handling, so if you call `colorvals('not a color')` you get back a more meaningful exception than `UnboundLocalError`.
- You should look into using a dict rather than a chain of `if` statements.

But I've made the smallest change to your existing code that does what I'm guessing you want.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to have a Function that returned your three values, and setting a,b,c with the function

```
def set_colour(colour_string):

    if colour_string == "red":
        return 1,2,3

    if colour_string == "blue":
        return 5,6,7

    Print("Invalid colour string")
    return None

a,b,c = set_colour("red")

z = a + b + c
print(str(z))

a,b,c = set_colour("blue")

z = a + b + c
print(str(z))
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do as @abarnert mentioned, you'd put these conditional statements in a function and call it with any color you want.

```
def color_sum(color):
    if color == "red":
        a = 1
        b = 2
        c = 3
    else:
        a = 5
        b = 6
        c = 7
    z = a + b + c
    print("The answer is = " + str(z))

color_sum("blue")
```